# SQL split blob field in rows

Tags: sql, split, blob

I need to split a blob field in several rows. I have to create a new row each time that I find a char(10) in the blob field.

I use MS SQL Server 2008.

The blob field contains rows like these:

```
ABCDEF12345 § CUSTOMER 1 § 01/01/2013 § 24/01/2013 § 12 [char(10)]
BCDEF123456 § CUSTOMER 2 § 01/01/2016 § 25/01/2016 § 12 [char(10)]
CDEF1234567 § CUSTOMER 3 § 01/01/2016 § 14/03/2016 § 12 [char(10)]
```

I need to split it in this way:

```
|----|---------------------------------------------------------|
| id |  field1                                                 |
|----|---------------------------------------------------------|
| 1  | ABCDEF12345 § CUSTOMER 1 § 01/01/2013 § 24/01/2013 § 12 |
| 2  | BCDEF123456 § CUSTOMER 2 § 01/01/2016 § 25/01/2016 § 12 |
| 3  | CDEF1234567 § CUSTOMER 3 § 01/01/2016 § 14/03/2016 § 12 |
|----|---------------------------------------------------------|
```

Thank.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Also add some sample table data and the expected result (all as formatted text, not images.) And show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Please, not as a comment. No one can read that. Edit the question instead.